# pythonic conversion of tuple string to date and float or currency

Tags: python, type-conversion, tuples

I have the following tuple and I need to convert it to date and currency (or float if code for currency is too verbose).  I'm not familiar with any packages that could do the job.

Could you suggest a pythonic way of converting?  many thanks!

```
inc_data =[(u'Dec 31, 2012', u'104,507,100\n', u'56,000,000\n'),
           (u'Dec 31, 2011', u'106,916,100\n', u''),
           (u'Dec 31, 2010', u'99,870,100\n', u'')]
```

I am hoping to get the following result:

```
inc_data2=[(2012-12-31, 104507100.00, 56000000.00),
           (2011-12-31, 106916100.00, None),
           (2010-12-31, 99870100.00, None)]
```

I can convert single variable using datetime.strptime('date_string').date(), And likewise, string to float using

```
num_string = u'100'
num = float(num_string)
```

But I don't know how to convert when the values are stored in a tuple. Also, I don't know how python treats null, so I use 'None' as desired result.  Btw, I actually have about 40 columns leading by date in first column.

Comment: What do you mean by convert it to date and currency ? Can you give an example of desired output

Comment: I was hoping the result mentioned above.
sorry, I don't know how to format the comment to insert code.  So I will revise the question.

Answer (score 0):

convert to a datetime object

```
from datetime import datetime

inc_data2 = []

for tupleValues in inc_data:
    date = tupleValues[0].replace(',', '')
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d %Y')
    print date_object

    currency1 = float(tupleValues[1].replace(',',''))

    if len(tupleValues[2]) >= 1: 
        currency2 = float(tupleValues[2].replace(',',''))
    else:
        currency2 = None

    tempList = []
    tempList.append(str(date_object))
    tempList.append(currency1)
    tempList.append(currency2)

    inc_data2.append(tempList)
```

here is the output
[['2012-12-31 00:00:00', 104507100.0, 56000000.0], ['2011-12-31 00:00:00', 106916100.0, None], ['2010-12-31 00:00:00', 99870100.0, None]]